# How do I change color of Mat-Checkbox when it is disabled Globally?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular5

I have used mat-checkbox in my project and have given it a custom color. but that color is applying on all the disabled checkboxes in which users are unable to determine which checkbox is checked and disabled...

here is my code for custom color when checked:

```
.mat-checkbox-checked 
.mat-checkbox-layout
.mat-checkbox-inner-container
.mat-checkbox-background
.mat-checkbox-frame {
  background-color: #00BCD2 !important;
}
```

Now I need different color when the checkbox is checked and disabled.
Need some help! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Remove background-color for `.mat-checkbox-inner-container`

Comment: If I remove that then it is getting its default color (yellow) when checked but i need it to be sky blue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code that I use to change the checkbox color....

```
.mat-checkbox-checked.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background,
.mat-checkbox-indeterminate.mat-accent .mat-checkbox-background {
  background-color: #00BCD2;
}
```

and talking about the disabled color just put the `color="primary"` to your `<mat-checkbox>` tag where it is getting disabled this will have custom disable color(dark grey) and when checked it will have a `#00BCD2(light blue)` in checkbox.